# Error for (-3115168180217096500, -1341719847298427390): ValueError - hour must be in 0..23 (will try again later attempt 2 of 5)

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to save 'Time'datatype in Cassandra using Java, In database it's storing differently like "-3115168180217096500" but it's shoeing correct value in Datastax studio and in application. But when i tried to copy to CSV or do the select * i am getting the above error.

> Failed to format value Time(-1521359640000000000) : hour must be in 0..23
>   Failed to format value Time(-1521964440000000000) : hour must be in 0..23
>   1568 more decoding errors suppressed.

[image]

Comment: It's just a timezone issue, If you store the time other than UTC then it's going to store like that.

Comment: as converted your time `-1521964440000000000` in [https://www.epochconverter.com/] is referred to 1965! check and correct the time.

Comment: Have you entered the rest of the time in the image yourself?

Comment: No , One was entered  by Ruby app and the other by JAVA